# OpenMP parallelization not efficient

Tags: c, multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize this code using OpenMP.

```
for(t_step=0;t_step<Ntot;t_step++) {
        // current row
        if(cur_row + 1 < Npt_x)     cur_row++; 
        else                        cur_row = 0;
        // get data from file which update only the row "cur_row" of array val
        read_line(f_u, val[cur_row]);
        // computes
        for(i=0;i<Npt_x;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<Npt_y;j++) {
                i_corrected = cur_row - i;
                if(i_corrected < 0)     i_corrected = Npt_x + i_corrected;
                R[i][j] += val[cur_row][0]*val[i_corrected][j]/Ntot;
            }
        }
    }
```

with
 - val and R declared as **double,
 - Npt_x and Npt_y are about 500,
 - Ntot is about 10^6.

I've done this

```
for(t_step=0;t_step<Ntot;t_step++) {
        // current row
        if(cur_row + 1 < Npt_x)     cur_row++; 
        else                        cur_row = 0;
        // get data from file which update only the row "cur_row" of array val
        read_line(f_u, val[cur_row]);
        // computes
        #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2), private(i,j,i_corrected)
        for(i=0;i<Npt_x;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<Npt_y;j++) {
                i_corrected = cur_row - i;
                if(i_corrected < 0)     i_corrected = Npt_x + i_corrected;
                R[i][j] += val[cur_row][0]*val[i_corrected][j]/Ntot;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to be efficient. Is there a way to use OpenMP more efficiently in this case ?

Many thks

Comment: You might be able to use use loop tiling to improve usage of the cache.

Comment: I suggest you trying performance tools (such as Paraver http://www.bsc.es/computer-sciences/performance-tools/paraver) to explore the performance of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, I would try something like this:

```
for(t_step=0;t_step<Ntot;t_step++) {
    // current row
    if(cur_row + 1 < Npt_x)
        cur_row++; 
    else
        cur_row = 0;
    // get data from file which update only the row "cur_row" of array val
    read_line(f_u, val[cur_row]);
    // computes
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,i_corrected)
    for(i=0;i<Npt_x;i++) {
        i_corrected = cur_row - i;
        if(i_corrected < 0)
            i_corrected += Npt_x;
        double tmp = val[cur_row][0]/Ntot;
        #if defined(_OPENMP) && _OPENMP > 201306
        #pragma omp simd
        #endif
        for(j=0;j<Npt_y;j++) {
            R[i][j] += tmp*val[i_corrected][j];
        }
    }
}
```

However, since the code will be memory bound, that's not sure it'll get you much parallel speed-up... Worth a try though.

Comment: +1 smart use of `#pragma omp simd` (the best feature of OpenMP 4.0 imo), and clever reorganization to avoid recalculations. Unfortunately OP - the vast majority of this program's execution time will probably be in the call to `read_line()`, which is not thread-safe. I can't imagine the parallelization to improve this program dramatically.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll, interesting that you think `#pragma omp simd` is the most interesting feature of OpenMP 4.0 because I find it nearly useless at least for x86 compilers. Maybe it makes sense on other architectures but the major x86 C/C++ compilers already do auto-vectorization well and those that don't don't support OpenMP 4.0 anyway.

Comment: With this solution it runs 25% faster on 16 cores (I didn't try it with less core). But as mentioned by @NoseKnowsAll , the majority of the execution is spent in the function `read_line()  `. so I don't think I could get much more improvement.

Comment: @Zboson In my recent wave propagation algorithm, it improved run time by over 50%. Auto-vectorization just couldn't see a lot of the parallelization available apparently. And it's much cleaner/robust than the alternative compiler-specific pragmas in my opinion.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll, that's interesting. I would like to know why. I suspect it's due to associative math. Did you try using `-Ofast`? Actually, that's the only case I can think of where `omp simd` is useful. It allows you to select which loops you want to be done using associative math without enabling `-Ofast` for the entire translation unit.  If OpenMP had an `unroll` construct it , e.g. `#pragma omp simd unroll(8)` to unroll eight times, it would be a lot more interesting.

Comment: @Zboson Interesting, I had not heard of `Ofast` before. Unfortunately, I don't believe I can use it because I need precision division. I'm not sure about the effects of `-fp-model fast`, but it's worth exploring. Thanks for the heads up. As for an unroll feature, I agree that that could also be useful. But the way I view SIMD vectorization anyway, it acts as sort of an "unroll" in that it'll just handle 4 or 8 loops simultaneously.

Comment: @Zboson I believe the 50% benefit came because the size of our vector processing unit is 256 bits (pretty large imo), and so it could handle a non-trivial amount of iterations simultaneously in the do loops throughout the code.